# Read last lines from log using tail in a bash script

Tags: bash

The objective of this script is to read the last 1000 lines of the log file. If the word "error" exists, show the affected line.
I used the `tail` command because the log file is updated every second.

I can not include the tail command inside a variable.

```
word="error -"
find1=`tail -n 1000 /logs/console.log | grep "$word" | awk '{print $A1}' `
#
#
if echo "$find1" | grep -q "$word"; then echo "Error: $find1"
        exit 1;
else echo "No errors"
        exit 0;
fi;
```

I want to have a exit variable updated all the time.

Comment: hi, I just briefly looked over and found two possible solutions maybe- check https://superuser.com/a/900134/447487 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45943/131334

Comment: It is not exactly that i want to make, look at the example i want to use the command in a variable, this is the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if tail -n 1000 /logs/console.log | grep "$word" | awk '{print $A1}'; then 
        exit 1;
else echo "No errors"
        exit 0;
fi;
```

This will print the result during the if statement if the word exists and exit

Not sure what you mean by "I want to have a exit variable updated all the time."
exit is a command - it will exit the script gracefully if the word was not found (exit 0), and it will exit "with errors" if the word is found (exit 1)